# Open a SHIFT_JIS file in Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, unicode, shift-jis

This is one of those things that seems like it should be laughably easy but I'm stuck...

I need to open a CSV file that is stored in SHIFT_JIS encoding and decode it to Unicode and also encode in UTF-8. It sounds like this is pretty straightforward in ruby 1.9 but I'm not feeling particularly adventurous on my production Rails app, so I need to stick with 1.8.7.

Any help would be appreciated.